How to weight principal componets by their variance?
I'm following the paper New ECOSTRESS and MODIS Land Surface Temperature Data Reveal Fine-Scale Heat Vulnerability in Cities: A Case Study for Los Angeles County, California, and I quote:

In accordance with Kaisers rule, only those PCs that had an eigenvalue greater than one were retained for analysis. The PCs that had
eigenvalues greater than one were then rotated using a varimax
rotation to improve their interpretation and maximize the dispersion
of loadings across PCs. These rotated PC scores were weighted by
variance and then used to reconstruct the original observations.

I ran PCA on 4 variables using the FactoMineR and psych libraries. All variables were normalized to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one (z-score) before the PCA.
prc <-  PCA(df_adapt_pca, graph = FALSE, scale.unit = FALSE)
eig.val.adpt <- get_eigenvalue(adpt.pca)
eig.val.adpt

The results are below:
eigenvalue variance.percent cumulative.variance.percent
Dim.1  1.9746259        49.377345                    49.37735
Dim.2  1.1408281        28.527461                    77.90481
Dim.3  0.7619571        19.053441                    96.95825
Dim.4  0.1216413         3.041753                   100.00000

Then I selected the PCs with eigenvalues > 1 and I performed a varimax rotation, like so:
# Extract the eigenvalues for the first two principal components
eigenvalues <- eig.val.adpt[1:2, "eigenvalue"]

# Extract the loadings for the first two principal components
loadings_matrix <- adpt.pca$var$coord[, 1:2]

# Perform varimax rotation
varimax_result <- varimax(loadings_matrix)

# The rotated loadings
rotated_loadings <- varimax_result$loadings

The results of the varimax rotation:
Loadings:
      Dim.1  Dim.2 
income     0.959       
ndvi              0.817
cs_dist   -0.226  0.732
education  0.937 -0.240

    Dim.1 Dim.2
SS loadings    1.852 1.263
Proportion Var 0.463 0.316
Cumulative Var 0.463 0.779


Here is my question: How can I weight the rotated PCs by their variance?

My initial try, based on this post was:
# Scale the rotated PCs by the square root of the eigenvalues
weighted_rotated_PCs <- rotated_loadings %*% diag(sqrt(eigenvalues))

# Reconstruct the original data using the scores and the weighted rotated PCs
scores <- adpt.pca$ind$coord[, 1:2]

# Use the weighted rotated PCs to reconstruct the data
Xhat <- scores %*% t(weighted_rotated_PCs)

# Adjust the reconstructed data to have the same mean as the original data
mu <- colMeans(mydt)
Xhat <- scale(Xhat, center = -mu, scale = FALSE)

# Convert Xhat to a data frame
Xhat <- as.data.table(Xhat)

# column names to match original data
colnames(Xhat) <- colnames(mydt) # mydt contains the original obs

But when I compare the outputs of the Xhat and mydt I get:
Xhat[1,]
    income      ndvi   cs_dist education
1 2.067341 0.6560899 -1.683479  2.184048

mydt[1, ]
      income      ndvi    cs_dist education
1 0.4087451 0.1262939 -0.3533639 0.3261632

Which is quite different. Am I doing the weighting wrong?
The complete code:
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(FactoMineR)
library(psych)
    
wd <- "path/"
    
mydt <- read.table(paste0(wd, "mydt.csv"), sep = ",", header = TRUE)
    
# glimpse(mydt)
    
# Z-score normalize
adpt.pca <- as.data.frame(scale(mydt), center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
    
adpt.pca <- PCA(df_adapt_pca, graph = FALSE, scale.unit = FALSE)
eig.val.adpt <- get_eigenvalue(adpt.pca)
eig.val.adpt

# Extract the eigenvalues for the first two principal components
eigenvalues <- eig.val.adpt[1:2, "eigenvalue"]

# Extract the loadings for the first two principal components
loadings_matrix <- adpt.pca$var$coord[, 1:2]

# Perform varimax rotation
varimax_result <- varimax(loadings_matrix)

# The rotated loadings
rotated_loadings <- varimax_result$loadings

# Scale the rotated PCs by the square root of the eigenvalues
weighted_rotated_PCs <- rotated_loadings %*% diag(sqrt(eigenvalues))

# Reconstruct the original data using the scores and the weighted rotated PCs
scores <- adpt.pca$ind$coord[, 1:2]

# Use the weighted rotated PCs to reconstruct the data
Xhat <- scores %*% t(weighted_rotated_PCs)

# Adjust the reconstructed data to have the same mean as the original data
mu <- colMeans(mydt)
Xhat <- scale(Xhat, center = -mu, scale = FALSE)

# Convert Xhat to a data frame
Xhat <- as.data.table(Xhat)

# column names to match original data
colnames(Xhat) <- colnames(mydt) # my dt contains the original obs

Below a sample of the original dataset (before the Z-score standarization) with 20 rows:
dput(mydt)
structure(list(income = c(0.0001063, 0.000106, 6.72e-05, 7.97e-05, 
0.0001197, 4.09e-05, 5.17e-05, 0.0001092, 8.62e-05, 7.27e-05, 
0.0001034, 0.0001159, 7.24e-05, 9.17e-05, 8.06e-05, 0.0001049, 
8.15e-05, 9.05e-05, 0.0001063, 5.99e-05), ndvi = c(0.434779405593872, 
0.519024193286896, 0.484442293643951, 0.358367592096329, 0.613705396652222, 
0.508738815784454, 0.705485105514526, 0.454894632101059, 0.396738857030869, 
0.408085465431213, 0.425091296434402, 0.360570818185806, 0.455742985010147, 
0.44114676117897, 0.498669385910034, 0.404618799686432, 0.51068776845932, 
0.295410215854645, 0.606453955173492, 0.46584877371788), cs_dist = c(1515.64929199219, 
3037.51879882812, 2663.20043945312, 1761.39184570312, 344.697448730469, 
252.047805786133, 5528.3486328125, 2387.2802734375, 2771.0546875, 
877.851745605469, 1342.23034667969, 3318.9130859375, 1075.06188964844, 
5190.70166015625, 739.960021972656, 4005.1572265625, 684.494079589844, 
426.935241699219, 1222.70263671875, 2597.5166015625), education = c(0.0001015, 
9.71e-05, 6.14e-05, 8.47e-05, 9.97e-05, 5.29e-05, 4.74e-05, 0.0001464, 
0.0001042, 7.53e-05, 0.0001143, 9.4e-05, 6.57e-05, 5.52e-05, 
7.98e-05, 9.5e-05, 6.98e-05, 9.64e-05, 0.0001063, 6.43e-05)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`2402` = 2174L, 
`2404` = 2176L), class = "omit"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000023dc7801200>)

R 4.4.0, RStudio 2024.04.2 Build 764, Windows 11.

FYI: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com

Based on the link in the comments, I managed to approach the issue (how to weight the rotated PCs by their variance) like so:
# z-score normalization
mydt_normalized <- as.data.frame(scale(mydt))

# PCA
pca_result <- PCA(mydt_normalized, graph = FALSE)

# extract PCs with eigenvalues > 1, this step is to identify the desired # of PCs
eigenvalues <- pca_result$eig[, "eigenvalue"]
n_components <- sum(eigenvalues > 1)

# PCA with the selected number of components 
pca_selected <- PCA(mydt_normalized, ncp = n_components, graph = FALSE)

# varimax rotation
rotated_loadings <- varimax(pca_selected$var$coord)

# calculation of rotated PC scores
rotated_scores <- as.matrix(mydt_normalized) %*% rotated_loadings$loadings

# weight the rotated PC scores by variance
variance_weights <- eigenvalues[1:n_components] / sum(eigenvalues[1:n_components])
weighted_scores <- sweep(rotated_scores, 2, variance_weights, "*")

# reconstruction the original observations
reconstructed_data <- weighted_scores %*% t(rotated_loadings$loadings)

# Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the original data
original_means <- colMeans(mydt)
original_sds <- apply(mydt, 2, sd)

# Convert the reconstructed data back to original scale
reconstructed_original <- sweep(reconstructed_data, 2, original_sds, "*")
reconstructed_original <- sweep(reconstructed_original, 2, original_means, "+")

# option to display full numbers
options(scipen = 999)

# comparison of the original vs reconstructed obs
# the original observations
mydt[1, ]
      income      ndvi  cs_dist education
       <num>     <num>    <num>     <num>
1: 0.0001063 0.4347794 1515.649 0.0001015

# the reconstructed observations
income            ndvi          cs_dist          education
  <num>           <num>         <num>            <num>
1: 0.0001071987   0.4290230290  1864.3736031922  0.0001081663

I'm not sure yet if this approach is the correct one, so if anyone has any insights it would be nice to comment.
